# What is the purpose of using ruby begin without rescue?

Tags: ruby

In looking at http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/08/25/unlocking-ruby-keywords-begin-end-ensure-rescue/ I don't understand the example

```
def create_or_update_batch
  @batch ||= begin
    BookBatch.create(book_batch.batch_attrs)
  end

  @batch.update
end
```

What if I had

```
def create_or_update_batch
  @batch ||= BookBatch.create(book_batch.batch_attrs)

  @batch.update
end
```

How is this different?

Comment: That's just an example in a series of examples building up to the final point, it isn't meant to be read or understood in isolation. The construct in question generally appears when the logic takes more than one line to clearly express and even then it is often written as an `if` (depending on the author's preferred style of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is just bad - for the described case, there is no difference in behavior (and the bytecode will look very similar if not the same).

`begin ... end` block can be used for grouping *several* expressions - for example, for memoizing the intermediate result of some heavy calculations without additional intermediate assignments, like

```rb
some_var = begin
  # a bunch of expressions goes there
end

# continue calculations using some_var
```

Actually, `begin ... end` block acts in pretty much the same way as `def ... end` does to define a method. And because of this similarity `begin .... end` is not used very often in the production code - in most practical cases it's better to move the group of closely related expressions into a separate method.

There is one case when this block can make the difference - consider

```
some_method while false
```

vs

```rb
begin
  some_method
end while false
```

In the former snippet `some_method` isn't called at all, while in the latter it will be called once. But this usage is kind of discouraged - it makes the code trickier (the same can be done in a much more readable way with `loop` and explicit `break`)